# Chart JS, backgroundColor not showing

Tags: charts, chart.js

I am currently creating a custom legend in chartJS apparently the backgroundColor is not showing in the generated legend. See the image below:
[image: click here]

generate legend code

```
barGraphQty = new Chart(graphTarget, {
                    type: 'bar',
                    data: chartdata,
                    options: {
                        legend: {
                        display: false
                        },  legendCallback: function(chart) { 
        var text = []; 
        text.push('<ul class="' + chart.id + '-legend">'); 
        for (var i = 0; i < chart.data.datasets.length; i++) { 
            text.push('<li><span style="background-color:' + chart.data.datasets[i].backgroundColor + '"></span>'); 
            if (chart.data.datasets[i].label) { 
                text.push(chart.data.datasets[i].label); 
            } 
            text.push('</li>'); 
        } 
        text.push('</ul>'); 
        return text.join(''); 
    } 
                    }
                });
                
                myLegendContainer.innerHTML = barGraphQty.generateLegend();                
            });
```

datasets

```
datasets: [
                                {
                                    label: data[0].item,
                                    backgroundColor: ['green','green','green'],
                                    borderColor: 'white',
                                    data:data[0][0]
                                },{ label: data[1].item,
                                    backgroundColor: ['red','red','red'],
                                    borderColor: 'white',
                                    data:data[1][0]
                                },{ label: data[2].item,
                                    backgroundColor: ['yellow','yellow','yellow'],
                                    borderColor: 'white',
                                    data:data[2][0]
                                },{label: data[3].item,
                                    backgroundColor: ['blue','blue','blue'],
                                    borderColor: 'white',
                                    data:data[3][0]
                                }]
```

I want to show the color of the legend. I tried to change the background color to this `backgroundColor['green']` it shows the color but the color in the graph changes to color gray. Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all bars within a same `dataset` should have the same color, you should define `backgroundColor` as `string` instead of `array`.

Instead of this...

```
backgroundColor: ['green','green','green'],
```

try this:

```
backgroundColor: 'green',
```